# XCode Different Concurrent Themes

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

Is there any way with or without a plugin to have two or more separate Xcode workspaces open at the same time ?

I want each with a different theme / colour scheme.

I often have two projects open which may have the same name, and would like to allow myself to easily identify which project I am using.